# Spring, handling redirects, mappings, etc

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf

I think I have a simple question for you. I can't get clear enough information about it.

Actually, I have a controller in which 1st (`@RequestMapping("/greeting")`) method returns `index.html`,

but 2nd method do things which cannot be done by 1st.

After this method I need to go to `/greeting` so to 1st method, not just return a template `index.html`,

because of something in this html file, it will not work.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding exactly what you want. Are you saying that you want to use a certain method, because it does something useful, but you don't want its return value, instead wanting some value it has internally? You could factor that part of the method out as a separate method maybe?

You might try to make the question spell out the situation a bit further to make things clearer.

Comment: 1st mapped method returns `index.html`, then I have a  2nd mapped method which inserts into database some values and after this I havo to go 1st method, not just to `index.html`

Comment: Can the 2nd method call the 1st method? If you don't want the 2nd method to return the `index.html`, then don't return the result of the call.

Answer (score 0):

How about simply returning the page based on the result of the call?

```
@GetMapping("/greeting")
public String foo() {
   boolean success = someService.bar();   
   if (success) { //can be inlined as needed; shown for clarity
      return "index";  
   }
   someService.updateDb(); //change the name of the method accordingly
   return "greeting";
}

@Autowired
private SomeService someService; //can alternatively use constructor-injection
```

Keep your complex logic in the service layer.  Use the controller to route requests.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but it would not work. I've just found a solution which is ridiculous easy. 2nd method should `return "redirect:/greeting"`.